# Cortar palavra com CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Eu tenho a seguinte div.

```
<span class="credit-font" id="valYearCD">2036</span>
```

Preciso que o conteúdo de dentro 2036 seja reduzido, e todo conteúdo que aparecer dentro dessa div, mostre apenas os dois últimos números, no caso seria apenas o 36.

Tem como fazer isso com CSS ou JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara como vc colocou CSS na tag da pergunta vou te responder apenas com CSS.

Repare que o ponto principal aqui é usa o `width` com o tamanho em **CH** (character). Então um `width:2ch` seria a largura de 2 caractéres.

**Opção 1:**

Usando `direction:rtl` e `overflow:hidden` no pai vc alinha o texto a direita em uma "janela" no box com `2ch` de largura. Não precisa de quase nada de css.

```css
.box {
    width: 2ch;
    background-color: #f00;
    direction: rtl;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size:3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="credit-font" id="valYearCD">2036</span>
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2:**

Com isso em mente vc consegue cobrir só os dois primeiros dígitos com um elemento `::after` por exemplo.

**OBS:** Repare que é só um css para qualquer tamanho de font, pois independente do tamanho da fonte a largura do box vermelho é sempre `2ch`

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 4ch;
    position: relative;
}
span::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 2ch;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<span class="credit-font" id="valYearCD">2036</span>
        <br><br>
        <span style="font-size: 3rem;" class="credit-font" id="valYearCD">2036</span>
        <br><br>
        <span style="font-size: 6rem;" class="credit-font" id="valYearCD">2036</span>
```

Comment: Ótimo, funcionou. Mas, vi que ele mantem o espaço dos dois primeiros números.

Comment: @FelipeGoulart na Opção 1 ele corta tudo mesmo, na opção 2 ele deixa os caracteres ainda na tela, Eu sugiro usar a **Opção 1**

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer desta forma (explicações no código):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){      // DOM carregado
   var elm = $("#valYearCD");      // elemento
   var txt = elm.text();           // texto do elemento
   var fim = txt.match(/\d{2}\b/); // pega os 2 últimos algarismos
   elm.text(fim);                  // altera o texto do elemento
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="credit-font" id="valYearCD">2036</span>
```

Comment: Ele só altera no click? Tem como vir por padrão já?

Comment: É só trocar a função de **onclick** para **onload** por exemplo.

Comment: @FelipeGoulart Alterado!

Comment: @FelipeGoulart Coloquei o botão com clique apenas para ilustrar 

Answer (score 0):

Amigo você pode utilizar a função text() do jquery para pegar a text e o substr() para deixar apenas os dois últimos números:

```
$('#valYearCD').text($('#valYearCD').text().substr($('#valYearCD').text().length - 2, $('#valYearCD').text().length));
```

Desse modo irá mostrar apenas os 2 últimos números do seu texto.

Comment: Não funcionou assim.

Comment: Qual erro apresentou amigo?

Comment: Nenhum erro. Apenas não funcionou mesmo.